# What are the advantages of conv2d_same over conv2d(,padding='SAME') in faster rcnn?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Why use `conv2d_same` instead of normal `conv2d(..., padding='SAME')` in faster rcnn?

`conv2d_same` code is on [Tensorflow GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_utils.py#L77).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conv2d_same` is absolutely the same as `conv2d` when `stride == 1`.

When `stride > 1`, i.e. the intention is to downsample the tensor, the applied padding is a bit different. From the documentation:

> When `stride > 1`, then we do explicit zero-padding, followed by conv2d
>   with 'VALID' padding. Note that
>
> ```
> net = conv2d_same(inputs, num_outputs, 3, stride=stride)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> net = slim.conv2d(inputs, num_outputs, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME')
> net = subsample(net, factor=stride)
> ```
>
> whereas
>
> ```
> net = slim.conv2d(inputs, num_outputs, 3, stride=stride, padding='SAME')
> ```
>
> is different when the input's height or width is even, which is why we
>   add the current function.

The difference is basically in spatial size that you get after downsampling in both cases.